# replacing php 7.3 files

Tags: command-line, apache2, php

I seemingly erased 2 files by accident trying to add a line to them, following instructions from a tutorial

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini"
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini"
```

^^ this was the command I used, now both `php.ini` files only have that 1 line in them...

I'm assuming I've made a big mistake.  How can I replace those files without reinstalling PHP?

Comment: The "> /etc/.." tells the interpreter to replace the contents of the file with what you used "echo" to send to it... It's possible you were supposed to use ">>" which causes the echo statement to be appended to the file, not replacing it.  Restore your backups, check your "instructions" and I bet it'll use ">>" and not ">" so you can try again

Comment: Which Linux have you installed and what is its release number? Please click [edit] to add that vital information. Please do not use Add Comment; all information needed to solve the problem should be in the Question, put there with [edit].